# Bad Indentation of Code

Tags: support, markdown, editor

I've been seeing many questions and answers with the first line of a method or class indented by a negative amount. I haven't been able to reproduce it. Maybe someone on the team can look at [Multi-threading calls in Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352987/multi-threading-calls-in-windows-forms-application) and get some idea of what's different about that text?

In particular, trying to edit it to align it properly causes some really screwy results.

BTW, I'm using FireFox 3.5.8.

Answer (score 2):

That example seems to be using quasi-random numbers of blanks at the start of the line, leading to quasi-random indentation of the code.  You can sometimes get odd effects if someone has managed to mix tabs and blanks, but that does not appear to be the problem with the example question.

Basically, people don't care enough about the layout of the code they're showing off.  They'll have to hope it doesn't come back to bite them when they're applying for jobs.

Comment: The OP replied something about it being a problem with pasting from Visual Studio. Yet the text in the answer didn't look strange. No tabs, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I've seem similar issues in the past and assumed that it worked like this

- Poster know that four space indent makes code
- Poster types four space
- Goes to IDE copies code
- Pastes code, which doesn't do whay is expected
- remembers (or reads the instructions) that the 01010101010101010101010101 button is what is wanted
- selects code (including the indented first line
- hits 010101010101010101010101011001
- doesn't fix the first line.

Comment: That's the 0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101 button.

Comment: @Rosinante: I'd upvote your comment, but it'd have a non-binary number.